# PHP SOAP array error

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I'm trying to consume a method, but it returns me that Login failed, but in SOAPUI it works normally.

I think the error is in the array I'm sending.

Is this my array compared to XML is correct?

XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="https://product.net" xmlns:trav="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Product.Report" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <int:Product>
     <int:request>
        <trav:Color>
           <arr:int>3</arr:int>
           <arr:int>5</arr:int>
        </trav:Color>
        <trav:Cod>1</trav:Cod>
        <trav:Price>
           <arr:string>1.50</arr:string>
           <arr:string>9.00</arr:string>
        </trav:Price>
        <trav:Size>G</trav:Size>
     </int:request>
     <int:Login>
        <trav:Pass>123456</trav:Pass>
        <trav:User>user123</trav:User>
     </int:Login>
  </int:Product>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My array:

```
$consume->xmlArray = array(
"request" => array(

    "Color" => array(
        array(
            "int" => '3'
        ),
        array(
            "int" => '5'
        )
    ),

    "Cod" => "1",

    "Price" => array(
        array(
            "string" => "1.50"
        ),
        array(
            "string" => "9.00"
        ),
    ),

    "Size" => "G"

),

"Login" => array(
    "Pass" => "123456",
    "User" => "user123"
)

);
```

Return:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] Login Failed. in /var/www/html/Consume.php:85
```

Function Class Cosume:

```
public function Product(){

    $client = new SoapClient( $this->wsdl_url, array( "trace" => 1 ) );
    $params = $this->xmlArray;
    $response = $client->Product($params);
    return $response;

}
```